# Is a three-column footnote layout possible?

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I'm contemplating the idea of a document layout where citations are author-year-style, but given as footnotes. That is, those notes would be (for the most part) very short, which is a bad match for the one-column footnote layout of the standard classes. One possible remedy is to consolidate footnotes into a single paragraph per page, as done (e.g.) by the `para` option of the [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{Author 2001} Some more text.\footnote{Buthor 2002}
    And some more.\footnote{Cuthor 2003} Does this text ever end?\footnote{Duthor 2004}
    Yes.\footnote{Euthor 2005}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to typeset footnotes in two columns (with the running text still one-column). This can be achieved with the [`dblfnote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfnote) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dblfnote}
\DFNalwaysdouble% no attempt to fit footnotes into a single column

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{Author 2001} Some more text.\footnote{Buthor 2002}
    And some more.\footnote{Cuthor 2003} Does this text ever end?\footnote{Duthor 2004}
    Yes.\footnote{Euthor 2005}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I'm looking for is a layout similar to that of `dblfnote`, but with footnotes typeset in *three* columns. Can this be done with reasonable effort? (I'm hoping for a clever hack of either `dblfnote`'s macros or of the typesetting routines of the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package.)

Notes: `multicol`-like column balancing is not required, and I'm indifferent as to whether column breaks within footnotes should be permitted or not (`dblfnote` offers both options).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50942/12850) can give some inspiration?

Comment: @StephanLehmke It's a great answer that makes me confident that my request can be solved -- though my problem seems to different/easier, namely, that no overflow from marginpars to footnotes is required (or permitted).

Comment: I understood that much. With "inspiration" I meant you could just delete the margin stuff from the code ;-)

Comment: I'm staring in awe at it right now, but (at least to me) it's not obvious what exactly should "just" be deleted. :-)

Comment: Though this might get tricky because I also use the margin as a "dust bin" for lines overflowing from the footnote area because of widow/orphans. The insertion mechanism practically requires that "height of *n*-column footnote area = height of footnote material / *n*", which is not good for column breaking.

Comment: I'm somewhat glad that it's not *that* easy. ;-) As I noted, column balancing is not required, but I'd rather not have too much whitespace between running text and footnote area.

Comment: Well but without column balancing you won't be able to use the insertion mechanism at all, because of the simplistic calculation model it uses for determining the page break.

Comment: I see ... In case of, say 8 (very short) footnotes on a page, could you add whitespace for a (non-existing) ninth note at the end of the third column? (This may be a simplistic idea, too.)

Comment: The point is, you won't have any space... TeX will break the page such that the space left for footnotes is exactly the total height of the footnotes divided by 3 (or any other denominator you choose, but the ratio is always the same).

Comment: How about rounding up this height to the next instance of `3\baselineskip` (here:the skip used in the footnote area)?

Comment: Well of course you can enlarge the entries in the insert box, as well as changing the quotient to be used, but it will all be very heuristic and risky.

Comment: That's also true for `footmisc`'s `para` option. ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides three-column footnotes. In all it provides four kinds of footnote layouts: normal, two-column, three-column, and run together in a single paragraph.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\threecolumnfootnotes

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{Author 2001} Some more text.\footnote{Buthor 2002}
    And some more.\footnote{Cuthor 2003} Does this text ever end?\footnote{Duthor 2004}
    Yes.\footnote{Euthor 2005}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great -- now I only have to get the `memoir` code to work for other classes. :-) I hope you don't mind that I added a compilable example.

Comment: I'm glad you added the compilable example --- I've managed to kill the Ubuntu OS where I use (La)TeX on my PC and am still struggling to get it back without killing everything else as well. I think that I based memoir's extra footnote code on that in the ledmac package. Do you really need anything else than memoir (or perhaps beamer?) ;-)

Comment: Let's just say that I want users of the standard and `KOMA-Script` classes also to benefit from three-column footnotes. ;-) And another thanks for the `ledmac` tip!

Answer (score 16):

**Warning:** `ledmac` package is deprecated, see *Update* section below for correction.

As pointed out by Peter Wilson, `memoir`'s code for three-column footnotes is based on that of the [`ledmac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ledmac) package. That is, one can enable such a layout also for other classes than `memoir` with the following caveats:

- Contrary to the standard classes, footnotes (here: the ones in the first column) won't be indented;
- The `ledmac` footnotes don't feature an optional argument to change the number of individual notes.

Also note that both the `memoir` class and the `ledmac` package permit column breaks within individual footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ledmac} % see Update section below
\footthreecolX{A}

\let\footnote\footnoteA

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{Author 2001} Some more text.\footnote{Buthor 2002}
    And some more.\footnote{Cuthor 2003} Does this text ever end?\footnote{Duthor 2004}
    Yes.\footnote{Euthor 2005}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Update

As @LaRiFaRi mentioned, the `ledmac` package is deprecated and we can use [`reledmac`](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) package instead. To do so, we could exchange the following two lines

```
\usepackage{ledmac}
\footthreecolX{A}
```

by these ones

```
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
```

Comment: `ledmac` seems to be deprecated. Could you give us an update with `reledmac`, if possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

With `bidi` package (well, sorry if you do not need bidirectional typesetting but it provides extensive tools for footnotes), you can typeset footnotes in 1 to 10 columns. In addition you can typeset paragraph footnotes too. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{bidi}
\threecolumnfootnotes

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{Author 2001} Some more text.\footnote{Buthor 2002}
    And some more.\footnote{Cuthor 2003} Does this text ever end?\footnote{Duthor 2004}
    Yes.\footnote{Euthor 2005}

\end{document}
```

In addition you can also control the direction of the column of footnotes. For details see the documentation of `bidi` package.

Comment: +1, though you might want to add a hint that the `bidi` package requires Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: @lockstep it tells me that XeTeX is required when I try to compile it with LuaLaTeX