# A problem with two column footnotes in XeLatex

Tags: xetex, footnotes, bidi

My file must be compiled by `XeLateX` and its footnotes should be sorted in two columns in each page. So I use this code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\twocolumnfootnotes
%_____Making special format for numbers of footnotes
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\hspace*{-1em}
\parindent 0em
\noindent
\hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss   
.\@thefnmark }       
#1}  
\makeatother
%___________
\begin{document}
\lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hia} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hib} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hic} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hid}
\end{document}
```

But the problem is that my special format for numbers of footnotes does not work at all. On the other hand, if I delete `extrafootnotefeatures` option, then the alignment of footnote columns will be wrong (It will become right to left, but must be left to right)!

So the question is how can I have two-column footnotes and have the first footnote appear in the left column?

Comment: Is this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194584/4736 what you want?

Comment: @KeksDose I tried `dblfnote`, but it ruins the alignment of columns. I want the first footnote to appear in left column, not the right one.

Comment: I suggest to ask your question differently, something like: how can I have twocolumn footnotes and have the first footnote appear in the left column? Add a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need  is the customization of `\footfootmark` defined in `extrafootnotefeatures-xetex-bidi` like this

```
\bidi@ensure@newcommand{\footfootmark}{%
  \ifdim\footmarkwidth < \z@
    \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footmarkwidth{%
            \hss\normalfont\footscript{\@thefnmark}}%
          \hspace*{-\footmarkwidth}}%
  \else
    \ifdim\footmarkwidth = \z@
      {\normalfont\footscript{\@thefnmark}}%
    \else
      \hb@xt@\footmarkwidth{\hss\normalfont\footscript{\@thefnmark}}%
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Here `\footmarkwidth` define the width of box containing `\@thefnmark`, in your case to obtain the desired format you can use this code (you need to define a font with `\settextfont`)

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}

\twocolumnfootnotes

\footmarkwidth=1.8em

\makeatletter

\bidi@ensure@newcommand{\footfootmark}{%
  \ifdim\footmarkwidth < \z@
    \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footmarkwidth{%
            \hss\normalfont\footscript{\@thefnmark}}%
          \hspace*{-\footmarkwidth}}%
  \else
    \ifdim\footmarkwidth = \z@
      {\normalfont\footscript{\@thefnmark}}%
    \else
      \hb@xt@\footmarkwidth{\hss\normalfont\footscript{.\@thefnmark}}%
    \fi
  \fi}

\makeatother

\settextfont{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hia} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hib} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hic} \lr{hi}\LTRfootnote{Hid}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]