# Footnotes in columns

Tags: tables, footnotes

right now I am generating a table which collects a few information based on different authors. I put the references as footnotes and as far as I got from the stackexchange here, I have to use a minipage otherwise I cannot use the footnotes (not resolved). Well that is working fine but the 14 references are listed in one single column. However, I would like to split it into two or three columns otherwise it looks really bad. The table (as picture) is given below as well as an example LaTeX code. I tried following the suggestions made here [Split LaTeX footnotes into two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134937/split-latex-footnotes-into-two-columns#194584) using the dblfnote package but without success. I guess it is related to my minipage / table environment.

Thank you in advance,
Tobi

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}


\def\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
%
%
%
%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
\hline
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 1&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 2&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 3&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 4&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 5&  
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 6&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 7&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 8&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} 9&
  \cellcolor{gray!10} Quelle
  \\\hline

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  

  AA & BB & CC & DD & EE & FF & GG & HH & II & 
  \footnote{Footnote 1}
  \footnote{Footnote 2}
  \footnote{Footnote 3} 
  \footnote{Footnote 4}
  \footnote{Footnote 5}
  \footnote{Footnote 6}
  \footnote{Footnote 7}

  \\\hline
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %   


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %   

\\\hline
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Test table}
%
%
\vspace{1cm}
\end{minipage} 
\end{table}    
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

[image: Table with Footnotes]

Comment: try `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`

Comment: You also might consider using package `threeparttable` to keep the notes within the floating table itself.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer I already checked that but it is not working. [para]{footmisc} does not help in that particular problem. threeparttable too. But maybe I have to change the structure then. At last, it is not working with the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without minipages, you can always use  `\footnotemark` and abuse of `\footnotemark[]` to make fake table footnotes.

The usual (in the journals that I usually read) is just add all the notes in the same paragraph or each in any new paragraph with the same width that the table, that is easier and more compact, but you can make columns with `multicol` package, or alternatively, to have a left to right order, use `tabto` o a `tabularx` environment. Examples:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tabto,booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{By column order.}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXX}\toprule 
A\footnotemark & B\footnotemark & C\footnotemark & D\footnotemark & 
E & F & ...  \\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}

\newcounter{fn}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{list}{\textsuperscript{\arabic{fn}}}{\usecounter{fn}}
\item Bla bla bla bla bla bla  ... 
\item Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... \newpage
\item Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla... \newpage
\item Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... 
\end{list}  
\end{multicols}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{By row order.}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\NumTabs{3}
\def\tfn#1#2{\makebox[.06\linewidth]{\footnotemark[#1]}\parbox[t]{.26\linewidth}{#2}\tab}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXX}\toprule 
A\footnotemark & B\footnotemark & C\footnotemark & D\footnotemark & 
E & F & ...  \\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}
\parskip1em\par
\tfn{1}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla  ... }
\tfn{2}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...} 
\tfn{3}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...}\par 
\tfn{4}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...} 
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{By row order (alternative)}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\NumTabs{3}
\def\tfn#1#2{\makebox[1em][l]{\footnotemark[#1]}\hfil\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{#2}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXX}\toprule 
A\footnotemark & B\footnotemark & C\footnotemark & D\footnotemark & 
E & F & ...  \\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\tfn{1}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla  ... } &
\tfn{2}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...} &
\tfn{3}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...} \\ 
\tfn{4}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ...} \\ 
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I will use footnotemark because the other suggestions were not working. Thanks.

Just one question. If A should have the footnote 1 and 3, how would you do that?

Comment: Ah I got it - stupid. Sorry, I  can refer using \footnotemark[1] :)