# Three column layout with three column footnotes

Tags: footnotes, multicolumn

I was able to find how to do three column layout of main text, for example using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12.9in, paperheight=9.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Following the advice in [Is a three-column footnote layout possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69458/is-a-three-column-footnote-layout-possible) I can also make 3 column footnotes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12.9in, paperheight=9.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\footthreecolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

But combining those never worked for me. How should I do it? In this example, it seems to try to fit the footnotes into the first third of each coumn. Result=crap.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12.9in, paperheight=9.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{multicol}
\footthreecolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In the end, I'd like to be able to typeset a text like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you combine the linked post into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added compilable examples.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can now use `reledmac` which lets you set the column width for footnotes in columns. In `ledmac` the width in the threecolumn footnotes is fixed to `.3\hsize` and your case leads to really small footnote columns.

With `reledmac` you can set it back to `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12.9in, paperheight=9.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\hsizethreecolX[A]{\linewidth}
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the result fits your needs I can't say…

Comment: Wow...Nice suggestion....