# How can I replace footnotes for non-floating marginal notes?

Tags: footnotes, marginpar

How can I replace footnotes for non-floating marginal notes?

I have tried to replace my footnotes for sidenotes with `footmisc` package's `side` option, but they continue to be floats, like every `\marginpar`. I don't want them to float around an anchor: I want these marginal notes flowing from the top of the page to the bottom, and with the capacity of being splitted between pages when needed (because some of them might be too long, or there might be too many of them).

Comment: An interesting problem.  So if there are only (say) three notes at the bottom of the page, they should still appear at the top of the page in the margin with no empty space in between the notes?

Comment: @jon Yes, like in [this book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=5-Rcl66cVcoC&lpg=PP1&ots=0Og7QT2hip&dq=Livro%20das%20mil%20e%20uma%20noites&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example.

Comment: Sorry, Here's the correct link to a sample PDF: http://globolivros.globo.com/downloads/pdf/Mil_e_uma_noites_vol3.pdf

Comment: Perhaps `memoir`'s `\sidebar` commands can be adapted to your needs.  Seems like a good starting point at least.

Comment: Maybe also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50942/12850) could be an alternative. Here, marginnotes which don't fit in the margin turn into footnotes, but maybe this is better than displaying them on another page?

Comment: At least related: [Send (and stack) \marginpar to the top or the bottom of the page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69517/send-and-stack-marginpar-to-the-top-or-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: This doesn't answer your problem but the memoir class provides for footnotes that are set in a column in the outer margin with the bottom of the column aligned with the bottom of the page, whereas you would like the head of the column aligned at the top of the page.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT** Original version using a newly allocated box register is at the end. This version uses the `\footins` insertion register to take advantage of the primitive insert capability to pick up the correct notes for each page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\newcounter{f}
\addtolength\textheight{-20\baselineskip}
\def\z{\stepcounter{f}\Roman{f}
\roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f}}

\def\a{One two three.}
\def\b{\a\ \a\ Four five. \a}
\def\c{\b\ \b\ Red green blue. \b\footnote{\z} \a}
\def\d{\c\ \c\ \c\ \c}


\makeatletter
\skip\footins\z@
\count\footins\z@
\dimen\footins\textheight

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\marginparwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%

\gdef \@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
\hbox{\color@begingroup
  \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page
     \box\@cclv\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\vbox to \textheight{\unvbox\footins}}
  \else
    \llap{\vbox to \textheight{\unvbox\footins}\kern\marginparsep}\box\@cclv
   \fi
\color@endgroup}}%
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\d\ Nine ten. \d

Five four three two one. \d\ \d

Red blue green. \d\ Yellow blue. \d
\end{document}
```

---

I think something like this (updated for `twoside`) ....

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\newcounter{f}
\addtolength\textheight{-20\baselineskip}
\def\z{\stepcounter{f}\Roman{f}
\roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f} \roman{f}
\roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \roman{f} \alph{f}}

\def\a{One two three.}
\def\b{\a\ \a\ Four five. \a}
\def\c{\b\ \b\ Red green blue. \b\footnote{\z} \a}
\def\d{\c\ \c\ \c\ \c}

\newbox\ftbox
\setbox\ftbox\vbox{}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\ftbox\vbox{%
    \unvbox\ftbox    
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\marginparwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%

\gdef \@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \unvbox \@cclv
       \vskip \skip\footins
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \footnoterule
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
       }%
   \fi
   \global\setbox\@ne\vsplit\ftbox to \textheight
  \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\box\@outputbox\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\box\@ne}}}%
  \else
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\llap{\box\@ne\kern\marginparsep}\box\@outputbox}}%
   \fi
  \else
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\box\@outputbox\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\box\@ne}}}%
  \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\d\ Nine ten. \d

Five four three two one. \d\ \d

Red blue green. \d\ Yellow blue. \d
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem I've seen so far is that some notes are being placed in the page prior to the footnote marker (although there's enough space for it in the current page)...

Comment: yes that's a bug really (no time to fix today) tex reads at least a paragraph at a time before deciding where the page breaks and any footnotes seen in the part that is not placed on the shipped out page will be grabbed early.

Comment: The edited version gives the following error at `\end{document}`: `! Extra \else.
<output> ...utpenalty <-\@M \@specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol \@startc...`, an error that, if ignored, will result in an emergency stop: `! Incomplete \ifvoid; all text was ignored after line 65. [where the \end{document} is --henrique] <inserted text> \fi`.

Comment: I just copied the file back from this web page and re-ran and it runs without error and makes a three page pdf however it warns (\end occurred when \ifvoid on line 75 was incomplete)
 which is clearly a bug so I'll update in a bit.

Comment: yes. Sorry, I forgot to mention that your MWE isn't affected by that error, but one based on `blindtext` was.

Comment: Yes the code's wrong: if it warns about unfinished if (which it does on my example) then that's an accident waiting to happen. I need to do the day job now though so it will be later.

Comment: I think the unfinished if it the `\ifvoid\footins`. Curiously, the error is intermittent (it appears in pagebreaks when using `blindtext`, but not with regular text?). Besides, long footnotes increase `\parskip` up to the footnote end.

Comment: yes sorry been busy:-) reusing footins is probably the right way but it might be safer to allocate a new insertion register that way I wouldn't have to check everyplace that the current output routine checks footins. sorry I ran out of your bounty time, just need to find a spare hour to dissect the output routine:-)

Comment: Thank you very much David, I'm looking foward to it! I thought we still had some hours and I was going to bounty it the way it is, but the bounty button is gone... :(

Comment: don't worry about it, I'm not desperately short of points:-)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! But I want a singles-sided letterpaper article-class document, with the notes in the right hand margin. When I run the code above as-is, it works, but when I change twoside to letterpaper, it no longer works. Is there way to make it work?

Comment: @Mårten what goes wrong, you mean literally taking the code above and removing twoside?

Comment: Yes, replacing twoside with letterpaper. xelatex says: ! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ... \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.71 \end{document}

Comment: @Mårten I get no error in pdflatex or xelatex if I change twoside to letterpaper (texlive 2012) (lots of underful box warnings)

Comment: I don't know what I did before, it works beautifully now! Now I thought of a potential problem though. Is is possible to make the right margin elastic to accommodate large footnotes, like the bottom margin does on a "normal" page?

Comment: Hmm I also noted that even though I enlarge the size of the margin, the footnote area remains the same, and the footnotes have become double spaced like the text, which they weren't before.

Comment: @Mårten the width is the standard LaTeX \marginparwidth length which you can set as usual. The code does `@parboxrestore, I'd have thought any code inflicting double spacing on the main document would have added single spacing to that so parboxes are not spaced out, anyway you could add single spacing to the code just after the call to that (of course the correct fix is not to double space the main text)

Comment: @David, sorry it took me so long to reactivate this question (I just read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3640 and remembered this :)). The `footins`-enabled version has one drawback: It adds a lot of whitespace after paragraphs in order to keep the footnotes near their marks. (iiuc, it also has two missing `\fi`s that should follow `\color@endgroup}}`); the former version halts at the the main text's end, and will not add new pages for the completion of footnotes. I believe something from `\footins` could fix the first version but that's way beyond my knowledge...

Comment: @henrique I can't remember what this was doing:-) I'll have a look at the weekend if I get time:-)