# Marginal Footnote on stub column layout

Tags: footnotes, margins

I am trying to place the footnote on the margin in the Stub column layout

with the help of the topic discussed in this forum  [Solutions given by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70312/how-can-i-replace-footnotes-for-non-floating-marginal-notes)

i am facing the below issues

1. when the paragraph split in to next pages those paragraph contains footnotes  , actually the footnote indicator is on the next page, but footnote print on the previous page
2. when float present on the page more space on the page and text flows on beyond of the page.

How to rectify this issue

MY MWE is

```
\documentclass[demo]{book}
\usepackage{graphics,showframe}
\newbox\ftbox
\setbox\ftbox\vbox{}

\newcounter{marginfootnotecnt}[page]

\newbox\ftbox
\setbox\ftbox\vbox{}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\ftbox\vbox{%
    \unvbox\ftbox
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\marginparwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%

\gdef \@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \unvbox \@cclv
       \vskip \skip\footins
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \footnoterule
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
       }%
   \fi
   \global\setbox\@ne\vsplit\ftbox to \textheight
  \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\box\@outputbox\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\box\@ne}}}%
  \else
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\llap{\box\@ne\kern\marginparsep}\box\@outputbox}}%
   \fi
  \else
     \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\box\@outputbox\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\box\@ne}}}%
  \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are,loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application.\footnote{The simple macro item: WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty}

2 WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. \footnote{Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it.} However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

3 Thirty-eight participants completed surveys assessing knowledge of and comfort with contraceptive care immediately before and after the curriculum; 20 participants completed surveys assessing the same domains 4--6 months after the curriculum. Data from surveys administered immediately post-curriculum demonstrated significant improvements in knowledge about and comfort with counseling about, assessing medical eligibility for, and initiating multiple forms of contraception. Many of these improvements in knowledge and comfort were maintained on follow-up


4 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

5 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.\footnote{Footnote on page 2}
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the\footnote{2nd Footnote on page 2} general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. \footnote{However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.} Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\begin{figure}[!b]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{A head}
language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. \footnote{The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving} loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, \footnote{and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions} that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\end{figure}

\subsection{B Head}
Thus you do not have to be a macro\footnote{footnote} language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional {statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and} read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) and the `\footnotesinmargin` command.

```
% marginfnprob.tex  SE 617139

%\documentclass[demo]{book}
\documentclass[demo]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphics,showframe}

\footnotesinmargin % put footnotes aligned in the margin

\begin{document}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are,loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application.\footnote{The simple macro item: WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty}

2 WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. \footnote{Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it.} However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

3 Thirty-eight participants completed surveys assessing knowledge of and comfort with contraceptive care immediately before and after the curriculum; 20 participants completed surveys assessing the same domains 4--6 months after the curriculum. Data from surveys administered immediately post-curriculum demonstrated significant improvements in knowledge about and comfort with counseling about, assessing medical eligibility for, and initiating multiple forms of contraception. Many of these improvements in knowledge and comfort were maintained on follow-up


4 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

5 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.\footnote{Footnote on page 2}
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the\footnote{2nd Footnote on page 2} general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. \footnote{However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.} Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\begin{figure}[!b]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{A head}
language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. \footnote{The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving} loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, \footnote{and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions} that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\end{figure}

\subsection{B Head}
Thus you do not have to be a macro\footnote{footnote} language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional {statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and} read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\end{document}

\usepackage{graphics,showframe}
\usepackage{marginfix}% just in case
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}

\renewcommand{\footnotetext}[2][\value{footnote}]{\marginpar{\normalfont\footnotesize\sloppy% or \raggedright
  \footnotemark[#1]#2}}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\empty]{\ifx\empty#1\relax
  \footnotemark\footnotetext{#2}%
\else
  \footnotemark[#1]\footnotetext[#1]{#2}%
\fi}

\end{comment}

\begin{document}


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are,loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application.\footnote{The simple macro item: WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty}

2 WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. \footnote{Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it.} However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

3 Thirty-eight participants completed surveys assessing knowledge of and comfort with contraceptive care immediately before and after the curriculum; 20 participants completed surveys assessing the same domains 4--6 months after the curriculum. Data from surveys administered immediately post-curriculum demonstrated significant improvements in knowledge about and comfort with counseling about, assessing medical eligibility for, and initiating multiple forms of contraception. Many of these improvements in knowledge and comfort were maintained on follow-up


4 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

5 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.\footnote{Footnote on page 2}
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the\footnote{2nd Footnote on page 2} general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. \footnote{However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.} Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\begin{figure}[!b]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{A head}
language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. \footnote{The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving} loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, \footnote{and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions} that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\end{figure}

\subsection{B Head}
Thus you do not have to be a macro\footnote{footnote} language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional {statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and} read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\end{document}
```

[image]

`memoir` provides a variety of page notes: bottom footnotes; footnotes in the margin either listed bottom up or aligned with the callout; sidebars --- text set in the margin and can be multipage in length. See chapter 12 *Page notes* in the manual (`< texdoc memoir`)

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I believe there is a much simpler solution.

```
\documentclass[demo]{book}
\usepackage{graphics,showframe}
\usepackage{marginfix}% just in case

\renewcommand{\footnotetext}[2][\value{footnote}]{\marginpar{\normalfont\footnotesize\sloppy% or \raggedright
  \footnotemark[#1]#2}}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\empty]{\ifx\empty#1\relax
  \footnotemark\footnotetext{#2}%
\else
  \footnotemark[#1]\footnotetext[#1]{#2}%
\fi}

\begin{document}


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are,loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application.\footnote{The simple macro item: WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty}

2 WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. \footnote{Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it.} However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

3 Thirty-eight participants completed surveys assessing knowledge of and comfort with contraceptive care immediately before and after the curriculum; 20 participants completed surveys assessing the same domains 4--6 months after the curriculum. Data from surveys administered immediately post-curriculum demonstrated significant improvements in knowledge about and comfort with counseling about, assessing medical eligibility for, and initiating multiple forms of contraception. Many of these improvements in knowledge and comfort were maintained on follow-up


4 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

5 Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.\footnote{Footnote on page 2}
Cirrhotic patients are more vulnerable to sedation-related complications than the\footnote{2nd Footnote on page 2} general population, and there is no consensus on sedation during endoscopic procedures for these patients, whose numbers are increasing globally. Our study compared the efficacy of sedation, hemodynamic, respiratory effects, the incidence of side effects, and patient and endoscopist satisfaction with dexmedetomidine-ketamine versus propofol-ketamine during upper gastrointestinal endoscopy (UGIE) in hepatic patients with Child-Pugh classification.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. \footnote{However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.} Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\begin{figure}[!b]
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{A head}
language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. \footnote{The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving} loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, \footnote{and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions} that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure Caption}
\includegraphics{murugan.pdf}
\end{figure}

\subsection{B Head}
Thus you do not have to be a macro\footnote{footnote} language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional {statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and} read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your timely help, i am trying to set the cued footnotes in the margin either top/bottom of the page