# Top Page Stacked Alignment of \marginpar, \marginnote or \sidenote?

Tags: align, marginpar, marginnote

I have tried several variations of moving my footnotes into a margin located at the side of the page. What I have not found in their respective documentations, however, is a way to break their alignment with the line they are called and rather stack all notes at the top of the page one after the other. This would eliminate most float/page-crossing issues people are dealing without manual fixes. What do you think, and/or do you know of a simple way of doing that?

Comment: It would be an idea to provide information about what document class you use. I know that the `memoir` class has side footnotes that stack in the margin at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am using the book class, memoir does unfortuantely corrupt many other things I already set (like a custom itquote environment and others). if possible, i would therefore prefer any option that works within the book (or report?) class

Comment: Normally it will be very simple to convert a document into memoir, but of course if you are using constructions like `\bf` or `\it` (which shouldn't have been used since 1993!!) then of course memoir will complain.

Comment: The marginfix package will move `\marginpar`s to fit the page, if needed.  The sidenote package appears to use `\marginnote` instead of `\marginpar` however.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617139/marginal-footnote-on-stub-column-layout