# "Dynamic Endnotes" (footnotes on side): what to do with footnotes at the end of the page?

Tags: footnotes, marginpar, footmisc

I want to use what Bringhurst calls "dynamic endnotes", i.e. footnotes in the marginpar. This can be easily achieved with the `footmisc` package. However, I need some support and guidance how to handle footnotes that are near the bottom of the page and hence extend below the bottom margin of the page. The MWE below illustrates the problem.

I am open to suggestion what to do with this. I think the following would be best:

- If there is enough space, push the footnote upwards so that the last line of the footnote is aligned with the last line of the text
- If there is not enough space (because there is a footnote above), let the footnote flow to the bottom of the page as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27998/notes-overflowing-from-marginpar-to-footer).

Is this typographically acceptable? If yes, how could this be implemented?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum,geometry}

\geometry{left=2cm,textwidth=130mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}

\usepackage[side,flushmargin]{footmisc}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulpu-
tate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris
ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibu- lum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent
eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla,
malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auc- tor semper
nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan
eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum\footnote{This footnote now extends below the bottom margin which
does not look nice. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Dynamic Endnote problem]

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so simple...the package `marginfix` seems to solve my problem of footnotes being below the bottom margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `marginfix` solves the problem regarding footnotes extending over the bottom margin. Overflowing marginpars can be achieved using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27998/notes-overflowing-from-marginpar-to-footer).